# Detecting Battery Charging Android

Tags: java, android, battery

I;m programmatically rejecting an incoming calls. The "call reject" and "sendSMS" work fine,
but I want to reject the call only if the phone is in charging mode.

I'm trying to implement the following code :

```
  case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

        if (isCharging())
        {
            reject();
            sendSMS(incomingNumber);
        } 

  break;
```

isCharging:

```
public boolean isCharging()
{
    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = contextMember.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
    int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean bCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                         status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
    return bCharging;
}
```

But the app keeps crushing on incoming call.

Please help me to figure this out!

I'm receiving the following errors on the LogCat:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160): android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException:         IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at     android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:163)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:157)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at   com.SmartDialer_app.SmartDialer.MyPhoneStateListener.isCharging(MyPhoneStateListener.java:106)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at  com.SmartDialer_app.SmartDialer.MyPhoneStateListener.onCallStateChanged(MyPhoneStateListene r.java:57)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:393)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160): android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:163)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:157)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at com.SmartDialer_app.SmartDialer.MyPhoneStateListener.isCharging(MyPhoneStateListener.java:1 06)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at com.SmartDialer_app.SmartDialer.MyPhoneStateListener.onCallStateChanged(MyPhoneStateListener.java:57)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:393)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
  E/AndroidRuntime(11160):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
 E/AndroidRuntime(11160):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "crush".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `isCharging()` method is presumably being called from `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`. In that case, you cannot call `registerReceiver()` directly, even with a `null` first parameter.

Instead of:

```
 Intent batteryStatus = contextMember.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

try:

```
 Intent batteryStatus = contextMember.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

See [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/12/real-use-getapplicationcontext.html) for more background.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I've leaned something. :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Add the permisions in you Manifiest File

```
  <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add this code in your class, you can set a varible flag isCharging and check is is setted.
The BatteryManager broadcasts all battery and charging details in a sticky Intent that includes the charging status.

The charging status can change as easily as a device can be plugged in, so it's important to monitor the charging state for changes and alter your refresh rate accordingly.

Ref:// developer.android.com documentation.

```
    public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;


        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
      //remove some variables if you don't need it.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity, create a new `BroadcastReceiver` instance or your class instance that extends it. Also create your `IntentFilter` and the intent to be filtered. Then in your activity, override `onReceive()` and add whatever you want to do when the activity receives the corresponding intent there.

You can instantiate the receiver class in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`.

Something like this:

```
public class YourAc extends Activity{
BroadcastReceiver br;
@Override
public void onResume(){
    //instantiate your intent filter and other related stuff here
    //register the receiver
}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    //unregister your receiver
}
@Override
public void onReceive(){
    //change the boolean isCharging to false
}
}
```

Comment: That should not be necessary. The code shown in the question is used for determining the current state of the battery.

Comment: @CommonsWare, True. I think you can register your receiver at the time you need to check battery status, and unregister after checking. So maybe overriding `onResume()` and `onPause()` is extra work.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes you are right. Thanks for pointing that out. Appreciated.